# Gradle setting plugin property from commandline

Tags: gradle

I'm using the java plugin with gradle. I want to put the test reports to a different location than the default (buildDir/testResultsDirName).

Within the gradle build file I can do this by setting the testReportDir:

```
test.testReportDir = file('path')
```

Now I want to set this property from the outside, meaning from the command line.

Unfortunatelly the following does not work

```
gradlew -Dtest.testReportDir=path :subproject:test
```

The reason why I want to do this is because in my CI I want to put the test results somewhere else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use gradle -P

```
-P, --project-prop      Set project property for the build script (e.g. -Pmyprop=myvalue).
```

I usually build my scripts to look for a commandline property and if it is not set use a default value:

```
ext.sourceJob = hasProperty('source_job')? source_job : "trunk-integration"
```

You can also do in a task (like JavaExec type):

```
if(project.hasProperty("jre1_6")) {
   environment 'JRE1_6', jre1_6
}
```

Comment: Or even better, keep all configuration for CI builds in the build script(s). Then you won't have to litter CI jobs with command-line flags.

Comment: The "hasProject" must be prefixed with "project."

Comment: That depends on the context. The second one I showed is within a task, the first is global.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I'm trying to find out whether the long version of `--project-prop` requires a space or an `=` character.

Comment: The help uses says "-Pmyprop=myvalue", at least on the version I was using at the time